# Github with vs Code wants to commit non-exisiting files

Tags: visual-studio, github

I'm facing a weird problem with github in visual studio code. I accidentally tried to commit big files to my remote repo. Then I got the `[remote rejected]` message.
I tried to add the folder to gitignore and unstaged with `git reset HEAD^`.
When committing vs code still wants to upload the big files.
Ok, so I deleted all files from the folder, unstaged again, but when I push to github it's still uploading the files and rejecting? How is this possible??
How can I get rid of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very easy solution is to

- rename the local repository folder to something else, like `deprecated`
- `git clone` the repository, so you will have a fresh repository and the damaged repository
- make the changes in the fresh clone (override the changed files, remove the deleted files)
- `checkout` the branch you were on
- `git add` without the large files
- `git commit`
- remove the old, damaged copy

Alternatively, you can run

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

However, the `[remote rejected]` might be caused by a different problem. Maybe you had multiple commits before you have pushed and the large files are not committed in your last commit. Also, it's possible that someone else pushed his/her changes and you need to pull first.